# Wikidata - Search of human instance that doesn't break

Tags: api, wikidata, wikipedia

Is this possible, like the wikidata autocomplete combo works, in a speedy way, with a filter of `"itemlabel strings start with..."` ?

```
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>

SELECT ?item ?itemLabel ?fecha_de_nacimiento  WHERE {

  ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q5.
  ?item schema:dateModified ?modified
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "es,en,it,fr,de,cs,[AUTO_LANGUAGE]". }
  OPTIONAL { ?item wdt:P569 ?fecha_de_nacimiento. }

  FILTER(?fecha_de_nacimiento > "1900-01-01T00:00:00Z"^^xsd:dateTime)

}
LIMIT 100
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose the problem is not that you're not familiar with [`STRSTARTS`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-strstarts), but rather performance.

---

[This page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wikidata-entity-lookup) contains some introductory remarks.

**Search in multiple languages**

If you really want to search in multiple languages, then, I'm afraid, the only option is to use wikidata.dbpedia.org as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45298496/7879193) on Stack Overflow.

**Search in single language**

If you want to search in a single language (according to [your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49203964/7879193) on Stack Overflow ), you can use [Suggest API](https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/wiki/Suggest-API) or call [Mediawiki API from SPARQL](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikidata_query_service/User_Manual/MWAPI#Find_all_entities_with_labels_%22cheese%22_and_get_their_types).

**Update**

The Wikibase Mediawiki API extension allows to use some special keywords on Wikidata, e. g. [haswbstatement:P31=Q5](https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&srsearch=arturo%20haswbstatement:P31=Q5&format=json&srlimit=100).

Comment: Thanks. Actually Im looking for: https://github.com/maxlath/wikidata-filter/blob/master/docs/how_to.md#by-something-else and get these information in an elasticsearch on my own side. But option 1 has some interesting information

Comment: @LeandroTupone, I'm not sure I understand what you are looking for. Are you looking for local solution? Then probably you just need to enable full-text index in Blazegraph.

Comment: Not actually, but I found this query is really impossible to make work with sparql and with mediawiki api. I was trying with dbpedia without success and now im reading suggest api.

Comment: im getting close with:
 https://tools.wmflabs.org/openrefine-wikidata/en/api?query={%22query%22:%22arturo%22,%22type%22:%22Q5%22}